# Identify cookies eaten in Corfu, Greece

Tags: food-and-drink, greece, local-cuisine

So, this is silly and irrelevant, but last year when I was in Corfu (St. George), in a local store I found some really delicious cookies, and I mean REALLY delicious.

I would like to somehow find out the name, so that a friend can get more for me :-) The packaging is similar to a standard cookies packaging, something like [example](https://greekmarket.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/600x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/8/8/8838764658718.jpg). The cookies inside are wrapped individually. Each cookie consists of two thin, crunchy, oaty, whole-grainy rectangular pieces glued together with chocolate.

If somehow, somewhere, there's anyone who knows what I'm talking about, that would be just fantastic :-)

Comment: So a commercial brand? Not homemade / small shop ones?

Comment: @MarkMayo Yes, commercial.

Comment: Try searching Amazon with something liked greek chocolate cookie (or biscuit). I got quite a lot of hits, including a bunch of varieties called Lov'it. Also try Google image search.

Comment: I am buying lots of cookies here in Greece. I could help you but I need more info. even a drawing might help

Comment: They are not these, are they? https://greekmarket.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/600x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/8/8/8838734774302.jpg

Comment: Was it the brand in your example, Allatini?

Comment: @papakias Nope, not those

Comment: @Giorgio Doesn't matter, I just picked a random picture :)

Comment: @Eutherpy can you give us some more info about them?

Comment: Broken link to jpg image :(

Answer (score 2):

Α lucky guess is this: http://papadopoulou.gr/products/biscuits/miranda/chocolate

Another guess would be: http://papadopoulou.gr/products/biscuits/digestive/milk-chocolate

Best brands in Greece:

- Papadopoulou: https://papadopoulou.gr/products/biscuits
- Violanta: http://violanta.gr/en/products/standard-products
- Allatini by Elbisco: http://elbisco.gr/our-brands/allatini/ (probably not what you're looking for)